# Nullreference exception in System.IO.DefaultWatcher.DoFiles at a c# mono MVC webapplication

Tags: web-applications, mono, nullreferenceexception

I have a c# Mono MVC application. Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 (from 11.4) I get sometimes the following error when I run my webapplication:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.IO.DefaultWatcher.DoFiles (System.IO.DefaultWatcherData data, System.String directory, Boolean dispatch) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.IO.DefaultWatcher.DoFiles (System.IO.DefaultWatcherData data, System.String directory, Boolean dispatch) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.IO.DefaultWatcher.DoFiles (System.IO.DefaultWatcherData data, System.String directory, Boolean dispatch) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.IO.DefaultWatcher.DoFiles (System.IO.DefaultWatcherData data, System.String directory, Boolean dispatch) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.IO.DefaultWatcher.DoFiles (System.IO.DefaultWatcherData data, System.String directory, Boolean dispatch) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.IO.DefaultWatcher.UpdateDataAndDispatch (System.IO.DefaultWatcherData data, Boolean dispatch) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.IO.DefaultWatcher.Monitor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Threading.Thread.StartUnsafe () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

When this error occurs is quite random. When it happens I restart the debugging environment (shift-f5 and f5 again). The errors happens about 1 in 5 times when I run the application.
Does anyone know what to do about it?

I use:
Ubuntu 11.10, Monodevelop 2.6, c# 4.0, xsp4, MVC 1.0, MySql, Nhibernate, Spring

Does anyone know what is causing this error and/or how I can prevent it?
Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it fixed:

- start monodevelop as root and run the application.
- start monodevelop normal again.

I don't know why the error disappeared but I haven't seen it anymore.